# Search record by name and display in data grid in VB and Access

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access-2010

I am a TyBCA student I am creating a window application using VB as a front end and MS Access as back end. As I am creating a Gym management system Software in it I cannot figure out what's the problem in my search code.

According to it should be like when I click on the search Btn a message box /dialog box should appear asking "Enter the Name to Search" and the result should be displayed on the Data Grid named "MS1" and "MS".

```
MS1.Visible = False
MS.Visible = True
Command4.Visible = False
Command6.Visible = True
id = InputBox("enter the id")
rr.Open "select * from tblMembers where Member_id=" & id, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
If Not (rr.EOF) Then
MS.Cols = 20
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 0) = "Member_id"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 1) = "First_Name"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 2) = "Last_Name"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 3) = "Gender"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 4) = "Membership"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 5) = "Address"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 6) = "Zip_Code"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 7) = "Date_Of_Birth"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 8) = "Mobile_No"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 9) = "Medical_History"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 10) = "Pay_Due_Date"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 11) = "Amount"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 12) = "Installed_amt"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 13) = "Balance"
MS1.TextMatrix(0, 14) = "Profile"

rr.MoveFirst

r = 1

Do While Not rr.EOF

MS1.Rows = MS1.Rows + 1
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 0) = rr.Fields(0)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 1) = rr.Fields(1)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 2) = rr.Fields(2)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 3) = rr.Fields(3)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 4) = rr.Fields(4)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 5) = rr.Fields(5)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 6) = rr.Fields(6)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 7) = rr.Fields(7)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 8) = rr.Fields(8)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 9) = rr.Fields(9)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 10) = rr.Fields(10)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 11) = rr.Fields(11)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 12) = rr.Fields(12)
MS1.TextMatrix(r, 13) = rr.Fields(13)

rr.MoveNext
r = r + 1
Loop
rr.Close
```

Comment: Someone has very kindly removed the line-by-line backtick formatting and applied the (much more readable) block formatting. This would have been quite laborious. Please take a moment to familiarise yourself with this tool - it is a button in the editor. Please also do not request urgency or special treatment here - most readers are volunteers, and will not take kindly to being hurried.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth nothing, but in your code you only display MS (first two lines), then only fill MS1.

Comment: Adduming MS ans MS1 are two different controls, you need to display MS1 once it has been filled. Try adding 'MS1.visible = True' at the end of your code.